# Socket Closed Exception in SocketImpl Setoption

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to set the `SO_KEEPALIVE` time of socket.

I created a class `SocketBuilder` to  build the socket instance with  SocketImpl. Source code is below,

```
public class SocketBuilder {

    private static SocketImpl si;

    public static Socket createCVPSocket() throws Exception {
        if (si == null) {
            init();
        }
        return new CSocket(si);
    }    


    private static void init() throws SocketException {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Constructor cons = null;
        try {
            cons = Class.forName("java.net.SocksSocketImpl")
                    .getDeclaredConstructor();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
                | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Not able to access socket implementation.");
        }
        cons.setAccessible(true);
        SocketImpl si = null;
        try {
            si = (SocketImpl) cons.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not able to create instance of socket.");
        }
        if (si != null) {
            si.setOption(SocketImpl.SO_KEEPALIVE, new Integer(60));
        }
    }

    private static class CSocket extends Socket {
        protected CSocket(SocketImpl si) throws SocketException, Exception {
            super(si);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket sock = SocketBuilder.createCVPSocket();
            System.out.println(sock);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting `java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed` exception. If I remove the line `si.setOption(SocketImpl.SO_KEEPALIVE, new Integer(60));` it works fine. But I  want to set the `SocketImpl.SO_KEEPALIVE`. How can I set the `SO_KEEPALIVE` of socket?

Comment: java.net.SocketException socket is closed This exception means that you closed the socket, and then continued to try to use it, Can you provide the socketImpl code

Answer (score 1):

There some errors in your code:

1. `SocketImpl si = null;` this declaration overlap your class field
2. `setOption` works only when a socket open/connected
3. You must close socket when you finish

   ```
   import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
   import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
   import java.net.*;

   public class SocketBuilder {
   private static SocketImpl si;

   public static Socket createCVPSocket() throws Exception {
       if (si == null) {
           init();
       }
       return new CSocket(si);
   }    


   private static void init() throws SocketException {
       @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
       Constructor cons = null;
       try {
           cons = Class.forName("java.net.SocksSocketImpl")
                   .getDeclaredConstructor();
       } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
               | ClassNotFoundException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(
                   "Not able to access socket implementation.");
       }
       cons.setAccessible(true);
       si = null;
       try {
           si = (SocketImpl) cons.newInstance();
       } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
               | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Not able to create instance of socket.");
       }

   }

   private static class CSocket extends Socket {
       protected CSocket(SocketImpl si) throws SocketException, Exception {
           super(si);
           super.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8888));

           si.setOption(SocketImpl.SO_KEEPALIVE, Boolean.TRUE);
       }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           Socket sock = SocketBuilder.createCVPSocket();
           System.out.println(sock);
       } catch (Exception e) { 
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Jiaano, Thanks for the quick response. I will do fix the errors you mentioned. I tried the code you shared but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed. I am trying to update the code to make sure the connection is active before setting the socket option.

Comment: At first you want make clear what you want, a server, of a client, second, if you want a server, you must use `Thread` `wait` and so on to make the server keep up

Comment: I was trying to create a client. I fixed the issue by updating teh code to, public static Socket createSocket(String hostName, int port,
   int timeout, int readtimeout) throws Exception {
  if (si == null) {
   init();
  }
  CSocket sock = new CSocket(si);
  InetSocketAddress endpoint = new InetSocketAddress(hostName, port); 
  sock.connect(endpoint);
  if (!sock.isConnected()) {
   throw new Exception("Connection cannot be established.");
  }
  si.setOption(SocketImpl.SO_KEEPALIVE, new Boolean(true));
  return sock;
 }

Comment: I don't understand why you use reflection, it is much complex than direct construct a socket, and there are plenty examples of socket connection, I think you find a working example is much easier

Comment: Yes, I agree. I wanted to set the socketoption directly instead of setting the socket.setKeepAlive().

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of `AbstractPlainSocketImpl#setOption` method,

```
public void setOption(int opt, Object val) throws SocketException {
        if (isClosedOrPending()) {
            throw new SocketException("Socket Closed");
        }
// Rest of the code removed for brevity
}
```

You can see there is a `isClosedOrPending` check before setting the options.

```
 /*
 * Return true if already closed or close is pending
 */
public boolean isClosedOrPending() {
    /*
     * Lock on fdLock to ensure that we wait if a
     * close is in progress.
     */
    synchronized (fdLock) {
        if (closePending || (fd == null)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, since you are just creating a socket, it will not have any fd associated with it. That is why you are getting this error.